# PHP: How to retrieve a file uploaded and saved on a web server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, file, centos6

I uploaded a file to the web server (I am the admin). Based on the code, the location of the file is at upload/. Can anyone explain where can I actually retrieve the file I saved on that server? When I run it I got the output of

> Upload: fly.gif
>   Type: image/gif
>   Size: 7.6962890625 kB
>   Temp file: /tmp/phplXtnZG
>   Stored in: upload/fly.gif

I tried looking into the folder path but I couldn't find it on my CENTOS machine.

Thanks,
linuxuser

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: file is uploaded into "upload" directory If you were created folder "upload" and given write permission to that folder. This folder should created the same path of your PHP script is running.

Comment: i tried creating upload folder in /upload, /home/username/upload, /var/www/html. Then, i gave all of them permissions. I still couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Its stored on /home/admin/web/upload/fly.gif

Comment: there's no web folder in my machine.